# Compatibility of conditional HTML-Comments?

Tags: html, comments

```
<![if lt IE 7]> code to be executed by internet explorer versions prior to 7 <![endif]>
```

its great and seems to work fine. but the only technical specification i can find about is at microsoft and it clearly states that its only interpreted by internet explorer.

so usual comments look like this `<!-- comment -->` .

my question:

could some browser end up with not interpreting `<![if lt IE 7]>` as a comment but as code and just displaying it plain?

i know that this qustion may not be well formed but i don't know how to rephrase it to be more precise. please feel free to edit and comment if its unclear so i can modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not**

```
<![if lt IE 7]>
```

it's

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

So no, other browsers that correctly parse HTML comments in the first place will always see the `<!--` that opens the comment block.

Comment: Just to point out, the first type is actually valid and in fact required when nesting. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17401

Comment: It's valid for IE perhaps, but no other browser is going to treat that as a correctly-formed comment. At best, they'll just ignore it, but it's not proper HTML.

Comment: Also that forum post is somewhat bogus.  Firefox doesn't get "confused" by nested comments, it correctly treats that as erroneous. You can't have the string "--" anywhere in a valid comment.

Comment: the upper version is already "correct" and is called downlevel visible comment. in my answer i quoted the ms manual i now found where the difference is pointed out

Comment: They're "correct" as long as they're *inside* a comment.  To any other browser (which I believe is the whole point of this question), they're fine inside a comment (because it's a comment) but they're not fine outside that context.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional comments are actually preceded by `<!--` **which makes them HTML comments**...

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
<![endif]-->
```

So if the browser supports comments then it won't display it. And I would guestimate that any browser made since around 2000 has supported HTML comments.

Answer (score 1):

reading a bit deeper at microsoft:

> When comparing this type of comment to
>   the basic HTML Comment, notice that
>   there are no hyphens ("--")
>   immediately after the opening "" of
>   the comment block; therefore, the
>   comment delimiters are treated as
>   unrecognized HTML. Because the browser
>   does not recognize the
>   downlevel-revealed conditional
>   comment, it does nothing with it.

and

> The downlevel-hidden conditional
>   comment contains hyphens ("--") in the
>   opening and closing tag, similar to
>   the basic HTML Comment. The condition
>   appears in the opening portion of the
>   tag, and [endif] is placed prior to
>   the closing portion of the tag. The
>   content is placed inside the comment
>   tags.
>
> Because the first four characters and
>   the last three characters of the
>   comment are identical to a basic HTML
>   Comment element, downlevel browsers
>   ignore the HTML content inside the
>   comment block. Since content is
>   effectively hidden from browsers that
>   do not support conditional comments,
>   this type of conditional comment is
>   called downlevel-hidden.
>
> If the result of the conditional
>   expression is true, the content inside
>   the comment block is parsed and
>   rendered by Internet Explorer 5 and
>   later versions. This behavior makes
>   the downlevel-hidden conditional
>   comment particularly useful for
>   content that has been specifically
>   designed for Internet Explorer.